# Load data from redshift using spark ad scala in an EMR

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr, spark-redshift

I am trying to connect redshift using spark with scala in zeppelin from an EMR cluster, I used spark-redshift library but it doesn't work. I tried many solutions and i don't know why it gives an error

````
   val df  = spark.read .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
   .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://xx:xx/xxxx?user=xxx&password=xxx")
   .option("tempdir", path)
   .option("query", sql_query) .load() ```


``` java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source:
com.databricks.spark.redshift. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:657)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:194)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
 ... 51 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.databricks.spark.redshift.DefaultSource
 at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:62)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
 at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
 at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:634)
 ... 53 more ```

Should I import something before ? or may be do some configuration
````

Comment: the whole log is needed - or at the very least the important part - the error message.

Comment: how about now ?

Comment: class not found..

Answer (score 0):

In order to run specific modules within EMR you must add those modules to your cluster.
(They are not there automatically)

Your error is saying that it cannot find the modules.
take a look at
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/powering-amazon-redshift-analytics-with-apache-spark-and-amazon-machine-learning/